# How the scope of the closure passed to SwiftUI.List initializer is embellished?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have this code:

```
struct MyView: View {
    @Binding var data: [ElemType]
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List($data) { $elem in
                VStack {
                     SomeView(boundVar: $elem)
                     SomeOtherView(nonBound: elem)
                }
            }
        }
}
Class SomeView:View {
    @Binding var boundVar:ElemType
    var body:some View{
        Text(boundVar.to_string())
    }
}
Class SomeOtherView:View {
    var nonBound:ElemType
    var body:some View{
        Text(nonBound.to_string())
    }
}
```

I understand that elem is the variable and $elem is the binding to it and it's type is `Binding<ElemType>`. I want to please know how is the closure passed to the List is embellished to contain the `elem` variable while I only have `$elem` in the arguments. I guess it is done through meta programming in the implementation of SwiftUI.List.

PS: I guess that below initializer for `List` is pattern matched to be used in code above.

```
@MainActor public init<Data, RowContent>(_ data: Data, @ViewBuilder rowContent: @escaping (Data.Element) -> RowContent) where Content == ForEach<Data, Data.Element.ID, RowContent>, Data : RandomAccessCollection, RowContent : View, Data.Element : Identifiable
```

Comment: lol holds the value and $lol is a binding to the value, somewhat simplified. lol is used when the value isn’t mutated and $lol when it is. So DetailView is for editing the object and CardView only to display it.